# What are the fantasy or sci-fi-related objects on display in Jack Rooney's bedroom?

Tags: object-identification, 3-body-problem

In the 2024 Netflix adaptation of *3 Body Problem*, there is a scene in Jack Rooney's bedroom. On some shelves, there are a number of toys/memorabilia representing a number of fantasy/sci-fi franchises.

The most obvious items are Captain America's shield, Mjolnir (Thor's hammer), a gremlin, and a miniature of a Ridley Scott/H. R. Giger alien. One other item looks like a Ghostbusters proton pack (and Ray Stantz's night vision device?). Also among many other items on display are what appear to be an AT-AT and action figures of Harry Potter and K-9 (Doctor Who).

What is the full inventory of items on display?

[image: Jack Rooney's bedroom]
[image: Jack Rooney's bedroom]
[image: Jack Rooney's bedroom]
[image: Jack Rooney's bedroom]